# Angular6 / AWS Amplify - Subscribe() cannot catch error from fromPromise()

Tags: angular, aws-amplify

I am currently building a Web app based on Angular6 and using AWS Amplify to call the API.

USE CASE: In the component, `submitForm` function calls  `updateProduct` function from the service. This call returns an error.

ISSUE:
At the service level, in `updateProduct` function I am able to catch the error (all good), **but at the component level, I cannot catch the error.**

QUESTION: Why? What am I doing wrong?

Here the code

The service:

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { AmplifyService } from 'aws-amplify-angular';
import { Observable } from 'rxjs/Observable';
import { fromPromise } from 'rxjs/observable/fromPromise';

@Injectable({
  providedIn: 'root'
})
export class ProductService {

  constructor(
    private amplifyService: AmplifyService
  ) { }

...

  public updateProduct(product: any): Observable<any> {
    const myInit = {
      body: product
    };
    return fromPromise(this.amplifyService.api().post('dev-myapi', '/product/' + product.id, myInit)
      .then(response => {
        console.log(response);
      })
      .catch(error => {
        console.log('ERROR API', error.response);
      }));
  }

}
```

The component

```
import { Component, OnInit, Input, Output, EventEmitter } from '@angular/core';
import { FormBuilder, FormGroup, FormControl, Validators } from '@angular/forms';
import { ProductService } from '../../../services/product.service';

@Component({
  selector: 'app-product-edit',
  templateUrl: './product-edit.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./product-edit.component.css']
})
export class ProductEditComponent implements OnInit {
    @Input() product: any;
    public myForm: FormGroup;

  constructor(
    private _formBuilder: FormBuilder,
    private productService: ProductService
  ) { }

  ngOnInit() {
    this.createForm();
  }

...

  submitForm(product: any, isValid: boolean) {
    if (isValid) {
      // Add Product ID
      console.log(this.product);
      product.id = this.product.id;
      product.type = this.product.type;
      this.productService.updateProduct(product)
        .subscribe(
          data => {
            console.log('UPDATE SUCCESS', data);
          },
          error => {
            console.log('ERROR', error);
          }
        );
    } else {
      console.log('Form is not valid');
    }
  }
}
```

And the console log:
[Console log](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5dy33.png)

Answer (score 0):

If you want to catch error at component level, in your service, either skip the catch, or after catching, continue to [throw](https://www.learnrxjs.io/operators/creation/throw.html).